# UIFeedbackGenerator and Airplay second screen

Tags: ios, airplay, uifeedbackgenerator

I'm building a second screen app (using AirPlay) wehre the iOS device is a remote control for the UI on the second screen. I wanted to use UIFeedbackGenerator (respectively UIImpactFeedbackGenerator) to produce haptic feedback when pressing buttons on the remote. I mean that's a perfect use case, isn't it? But when the second screen connects, there is no more feedback. It seams to me that this is either wanted behaviour or a bug.

Documentation doesn't say anything about it: [UIFeedbackGenerator class reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator)

Does anybody have an idea?